# Requiring private library in saga with hermes engine enabled causing max call stack size exceeded (native stack depth)

Tags: react-native, redux-saga, callstack, react-native-hermes

I'm currently trying to migrate our React Native application to leverage the hermes engine. When running the rootsaga with `sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)` we are getting the error: `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (native stack depth), js engine: hermes`.

The saga's `yield call` a controller, which imports a private (npm pkg) api client to make the desired request before returning the result to the saga. The import of the npm package is causing the error to occur, however it worked completely fine with hermes disabled.

I don't believe it's a recursion trap (could be wrong) but rather as the errors says, the call stack size created when calling the api client package. Would this make sense? I've tried both spawning and forking the saga's to no avail.
I believe the call stack size can be increased but I feel this is a workaround and am not sure under which circumstances it should be changed. I feel this stack should have no issues running.

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer.
The private api client module which was being imported was leveraging ajv for schema validation. The multitude of schema's was causing the max callstack issue within ajv. See https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv/issues/1581 for more details.